# Headless flash-based mp3 player

Tags: flash, mp3, headless

Do you know any headless flash-based mp3 player scriptable trough javascript?
I just need a public API to control playback (load, play, stop, seek) and a set of capturable events (onLoad, onPlay, onStop, onEnd). I need no UI, no helper scripts to embed the player, no support for playlists... and I'm spending so much time with no results.

I just need a fallback system for browsers that do not support HTML5 audio tag.

Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: Just build it. Should be less then a days work.

Answer (score 2):

[SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) should do that fine.

Another, much more experimental option would be to take a look at [GWT voices project](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-voices/) and check how it interacts with Flash.

Comment: no, sorry. soundmanager2 actually has everything I don't need. I don't need a debug console and different ways of interacting with the player. I know I can archieve whatever I need with it but I need something lightweight and highly customizable (I'm trying to implement an infinite radio webapp ala Pandora) .

Comment: It comes with a minimified version without debug code. 32 KB uncompressed.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small tutorial and two templates for a really tiny such mp3 player that I found.

The player's capabilites are:

- play
- pause
- stop
- loop on/off

Read [here](http://linuxmeerkat.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/headless-mp3-player/).